# Is Rory still plastic (and follow up questions)?

Tags: doctor-who

After the events in [The Big Bang](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Big_Bang), is [Rory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rory_Williams) still [plastic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auton)?

If not, then how is it that he remembers 1000 years of being a centurion?

(“He has a name but the people of our world know him better. As The Last Centurion” - Amy Pond)

If yes, then how has he fathered a child?

Answer (score 27):

He's not plastic.  After the Doctor flew the Pandorica into the Sun/TARDIS that rebooted the universe.  So that restored Rory to being human.  However, due to... timey-wimey, he, Amy, River, and the Doctor still remember the TARDIS exploding and ending the universe, along with the 2000-year wait.

As he is human, I think we all understand how he fathered a child.

Comment: That [Special time traveler privilege] might explain Rory remembering everything, but if Amy is right, so do the people of the earth.

Comment: I had the feeling it was indicated that Rory and Amy had forgotten the Doctor until Amy saw River Song's journal and the memories the Doctor planted came back to her.  And it seemed like everything unlocked all at once.  It seemed to me like it was all there, in their heads, it just needed to be unlocked.  But as to how River Song remembered it, well I hope we find out about that later.

Comment: This is somewhat related to my answer on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/how-did-river-song-know-to-go-to-earth-after-the-events-of-the-big-bang/3811 - despite both Rory's and the Doctor's un-existing, Amy was still able to remember both of them.  Whatever happened in the cracks doesn't entirely remove the victim from the timestream, but it isn't particularly clear what does happen.

Comment: @IanPugsley Thanks for the link, I kept forgetting to add an answer to that now that we have more information on River. (Spoilers!)

Comment: How can Rory remember something he wasn't there for? Because the plastic thing wasn't him so Rory was never there it was just the memory him . I.E. Rory from Amy's Perspective.

Answer (score 7):

Rory got rewritten to a non-automaton version.  Although not directly addressed, the reasoning behind this is that when the Doctor flew the Pandorica into the exploding TARDIS to form a universe-wide restoration field (gobbledy-gook from the episode) everything that happened due to the cracks was reversed.

Basically the universe gets rewound to a point before the cracks, at which point Rory had been (and always had been) alive in a non-automaton form.  This reversal was shown by Amy's parents re-appearing because, as the Doctor points out, they must have been stolen by the cracks.

As far as I can tell, they don't explain why Amy remembering the Doctor causes him to reappear.