# Was Rory "restored" after The Big Bang?

Tags: doctor-who, amy-pond

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Rory still plastic (and follow up questions)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/is-rory-still-plastic-and-follow-up-questions)

Regarding the Season 5 finale of Doctor Who; In the first part,

> Rory is returned to the show, as some kind of "Dalek/Cybermen/... alliance" abomination Plastic recreation of the original Rory. However Amy, with her last breath, makes him snap out of this instruction-following-mode and behave like the real Rory in all regards.

Later, in the second part,

> the whole stars being removed from history thing is (naturally) fixed by the Doctor. And we see Amy and Rory at their wedding.

However, from being called

> Roman Rory and The Boy Who Waited (two thousand years!)

later on, I didn't quite get whether the Rory we see later on is (and here comes the question)

> the actual flesh and blood Rory or the Plastic-Rory.

Bonus question: If everything was rewritten, how come everybody remembers everything?

Comment: After all the effort I went to answering, only to find out it's a duplicate and I could've copied and pasting their answer! ;)

Comment: @dlanod Your answer now appears on the older question, where hopefully it will get more recognition :-)