# Is Rory still an auton in "The Angels Take Manhattan"?

Tags: doctor-who

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Rory still plastic (and follow up questions)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/is-rory-still-plastic-and-follow-up-questions)

In the previous series, we learn that Rory is in fact an Auton, the Doctor reveals he doesn't know how long Rory will survive for but "it definitely won't be forever."

Fast forward to "The Angels Take Manhattan", Rory is shown having died at age 82, and before the paradox is created we see the old Rory die in the hotel room. Now it could have just been he was 82 years off his death when he was zapped back in time, but this seems quite a coincidence considering he was there for 2000 years beforehand without showing any signs of age at all.

Is it a coincidence and he's still an Auton, or did something else happen to "reset" him to a human (which is seemingly how he behaves in this episode?)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, Rory is still human.

After "The Big Bang" (Season 5. Episode 13) Rory was never an Auton, tho his human self retains the memory of his time as "the Last Centurion" while he waited for Amy.

> After a tearful reunion with Amy, the Doctor pulled them away to
>   rescue River Song. On their way, Auton Rory informed the Doctor about
>   his earlier encounter with the "future Doctor", which led to the
>   Doctor taking care of old business. Ultimately, the Doctor piloted the
>   Pandorica into the heart of the exploding TARDIS, **which restored the
>   universe, but also rewrote much of history.** The Doctor was removed
>   from reality. With him gone, the Auton version of Rory was likewise
>   removed from history. The original, human Rory was restored, his death
>   having never occurred.

See the tardis wikia [article](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Rory_Williams_%28Auton%29) on Auton Rory, where this info comes from.

Also:

> Although the Auton Rory now never existed, elements of his memory
>   remained to the human Rory. After Amy restored the Doctor and the
>   TARDIS through her own memories, **Rory likewise remembered having been
>   an Auton, saying, "I was plastic!"**

Comment: Ahah, thanks for that - makes a lot more sense now! I had seen that episode but didn't click that's what happened.

Comment: The Doctor explains this in "A Good Man Goes to War" (season 6 ep. 7) at about 32 min. in.

Comment: But, why was Auton Rory removed?

Answer (score 2):

This is going to spoil some of season 5/6, if you haven't seen all of it:

> When the universe is recreated from the pandorica colliding with the exploding tardis, the universe (including Rory) is reset to how to how it used to be.

With that effectively closing the time loop where he is an auton, he's now human.